# Bind Icon into contextMenuStrip add command c#

Tags: c#, icons, command, addition

I'm searching for way to include a icon with this command:

contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Name");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even try to find the answer on google? Here you go:

```
var item = new ToolStripMenuItem("Name");
    item.Image = Properties.Resources.Icon;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I did, but I'm total n00b in c# sharp ;/ didn't got it runnign even with your comment

Comment: No problem. You right click on your project in the project explorer and select properties. There you select the resources tab and in the upper part of it you select "Add existing file". After this you can select your file. In the code where it says "Properties.Resources.Icon" you have to replace icon with the name of your new resource.

Comment: Here is a video explaining it: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQMDsJgMXhE)

Comment: Is der there a simple addition to add a function call to your example?